# Downloads from Firebase Storage always time out

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I've got a Dart application which is attempting to download from Firebase Storage. Here's the specific lines of code which do the download:

```
var storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('gs://myapp_test/test.yaml');
int size = megs * 1024;
var data = await storageRef.getData(size);
```

The `test.yaml` file was uploaded from the command line and had global permissions set using:

```
gcloud storage buckets add-iam-policy-binding gs://myapp-test --member=allUsers --role=roles/storage.objectViewer
```

... and I've verified I can download it from the command line and through the web using an anonymous session in less than 1 second. But when I run the code, it always times out with:

```
[firebase_storage/retry-limit-exceeded] Firebase Storage: Max retry time for
operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it pure Dart or Flutter app? How are you configuring your Firebase credentials in the app? Ref usually refers to a path relative to your bucket root, not using the "gs://"

Comment: It's Flutter. I used `ref` because I was getting the identical error with `refFromURL`. I tried changing it to `var storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(bucket: 'gs://myapp'); var ref = storage.ref('/'); print(await ref.listAll());` and I get the same error.

My credentials were loaded with `_firebaseInit = Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);` using the autogenerated credentials file.